# Why is there a buffer before an SD socket?

Tags: arduino, can, sd, buffer, nucleo

I'm studying the SD card section of an electronic circuit of Sparkfun can bus shield that I have to connect on a Nucleo STM32F411RE. 
In the electriconic circuit, that you can see [here](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Shields/SparkFun_CAN-Bus_Shield_v13a.pdf).

There is a HEX_CONVERTER before the microSD socket (page 2). Looking at the board, I have seen that this Hex_converter is a 74HC4050 Integrated Circuit.
I really don't know what is its function. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely for input protection or 5V/3.3V level conversion. If you open the [datasheet of the part](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC4050.pdf), it says:

> The 74HC4050 is a hex buffer with over-voltage tolerant inputs. Inputs
>   are overvoltage tolerant to 15 V which enables the device to be used
>   in HIGH-to-LOW level shifting applications.

Comment: Hi Armandas and thanks for your answer. Yeah, you are right, but what happens if we have a 3V3 input? 
My question was caused by the words "HIGH
-to-LOW level shifter" on the title of the datasheet. Can you explain me why is this the title? Why it is called Hex converter?

Comment: @Bernheart High-to-Low means the device *can* be used in situations where input signal voltage is greater than the supply voltage to the chip. In this situation, up to 15 V. You can also drive the inputs with 3.3V or less (see Vih spec in the datasheet) and the buffer will work just fine.

Comment: @Bernheart I don't know where you found the word "converter". The part is "non-inverting buffer". Hex simply means that there are six channels.

Comment: I have found the word in the schematic file of the board, that you can see at the link I have posted (see page 2, bottom left corner)

Comment: @Bernheart Oh I see. The converter probably means "level converter" then...

Comment: ..then I was thinking that it was an exadecimal converter! ahahah when I have read this for first time I was getting crazy!

Comment: @Bernheart Please don't forget to upvote any answers that help you. It will motivate people to answer your questions!

Comment: Yet done, Armandas! but the site showed this:
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Answer (score 1):

SparkFun's CAN bus shield is designed such that it can be used with Arduino.
The SPI logic-level on Arduino is 5V and microSD card works at 3V3. 74HC4050 acts as a logic-level converter.

You can convert the logic-level by pass transistors but that would be slow if you demand speed on SPI Lines. (SPI CLK and DATA lines can go up to MHz range; hence transistors need to switch faster)